# Did the following characters of Gotei 13 make it alive?

Tags: bleach

Did ...

> Kisuke Urahara and Yoruichi Shihōin

survive the Thousand Year Blood War Arc?

The manga **did not** mention anything about them in the last chapter. They are both very important characters to the Bleach universe.

I am wondering if there were any subtle hints left by the author of Bleach  manga, Tite Kubo, to assert their death (or survival) in anyway.

Comment: The conclusion didn't conclude quite a lot of things.  I've not heard of any indication of that being rectified, but possibly there will be a data book or something.

Answer (score 3):

Urahara's status is unknown; however it is safe to presume he is dead. During his fight with Askin, although he defeats Askin (with a little help from Grimmjow), he collapses at the end and says that he apologizes for leaving. everything to Ichigo and Rukia.

Yoruichi is also unknown; after Askin activates his Vollstandig and approaches both of them, she does not appear after that. Her drug was wearing off, but Kubo did not reference back to her after that. With her, it isn't safe to assume her death or survival.

Comment: Though we do know that Nel was going to try and Rescue them.

Comment: @Ryan, yes, but I doubt Nel would be enough to overpower Askin.

Comment: Though, Askin was kind of already dead by then, you know, heart ripped out and everything. Nel just needed to pick them up and carry them out, in an unspecified but short period of time, through a small hole.

Answer (score 0):

In the light novel *WE DO knot ALWAYS LOVE YOU*, it is shown that Yoruichi Shihoin

> has become an instructor in the Soul Reaper Academy. While I forgot about Kisuke but he is alive as well.

As for Grimmjow and Nelliel, as shown in the novel *Can't Fear Your Own World*,

> they are shown to be alive and well. They also unlock a power beyond that of Resurreccion.